# running a mysql query using mysql-npm on AWS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda

Hi guys I have a problem that i don't really have idea how to solve. it's also a bit strange :/
Basically I have created this Lambda function to connect to a mysql DB using the node package 'mysql'.

If i run the function from command line on my pc using the command 'sls function run function1' and make different queries everything is fine.
But when I call the function from a web browser using the link, I have to refresh the page 2 times to get the right result because at the first refresh the server respond with the old result.

I have noticed that from the command line I always have different thredID while from webbrowser is always the same.

Also I don't close the connection in the lambda function code because everything is fine if i run the function from command line but from browser I can only make 2 queries and then I get a message that say that I cannot use a closed connection.

So it seems like Lambda store the old query result when I call it from web browser.

Obviously I'm making same stupid mistake but I don't know how to solve it.
Does anyone have an idea?
Thanks :)

```js
'use strict';
//npm packages
var mysql=require('mysql');
var deasync = require('deasync');

//variables
var goNext=false;    //use to synchronize deasync
var error=false;      //it becomes TRUE if an error occured during the connection to the DB
var dataColumnTable;  //the data thet you extract from the query to the DB
var errorMessage;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

//always same credentials
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host     : 'hostAddress',
       user     : 'Puser',
      password : 'password',
       port     : '3306',
       database : 'database1',
  });

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

module.exports.handler = function(event, context) {

var Email=event.email;


connection.query('SELECT City, Address FROM Person WHERE E_Mail=?', Email, function(err, rows) {
  
   if(err){
    console.log("Cannot connect to DB");
    console.log(err);
    error=true;
    errorMessage=err;
   }
   else{
    console.log("data from column acquired!");
    dataColumnTable=rows;
   }
   
   //connection.end(function(err) {
     //       connection.destroy();   
   //}); 
   //console.log("Connection closed!");
   goNext=true;
});

require('deasync').loopWhile(function(){return goNext!=true;});

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


if(error==true)
 return callback('Error '+ errorMessage);
else 
 return callback(null,dataColumnTable); //return a JsonFile
 
//fine headler
};
```

Comment: I guess this issue is not related to Lambda it is happening due to Webbrowser caching the result. Try dialing browser cache and see if happens

Comment: @error2007s ok thanks I'll try this solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm not *very* familiar with AWS and/or AWS Lambda.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/programming-model-v2.html states (emphasis mine):

> Your Lambda function code must be written in a stateless style, and have no affinity with the underlying compute infrastructure. Your code should expect local file system access, child processes, and similar artifacts to be **limited to the lifetime of the request**. Persistent state should be stored in Amazon S3, Amazon DynamoDB, or another cloud storage service. Requiring functions to be stateless enables AWS Lambda to launch as many copies of a function as needed to scale to the incoming rate of events and requests. These functions may not always run on the same compute instance from request to request, and a **given instance of your Lambda function may be used more than once** by AWS Lambda.

Opening a connection and storing it in a variable outside your handler function is state. The connection will likely be closed between requests or even before your first request. Your lambda function may be reused (hence identical thread ids).

My assumption would be (and an attempt to solve this problem), that you need to create the connection on every request (i.e., inside your handler) and may not expect any value be as initialized or as on last request. (except for constants probably).

Comment: I've tried your solution and it works!! Thanks for your help I was becoming crazy to find a solution, you were very helpful :)

Comment: then would you mind marking my post as the answer? ;o)